# Explain why $T: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$ is onto $\Bbb R^n$ (if invertible)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

What I know:
$T: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$ is invertible if there exists a function $S:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n $ such that
$$S(T(\vec x)) = \vec x \quad \forall \vec x \in \Bbb R^n \quad (1)$$
$$T(S(\vec x)) = \vec x \quad \forall x \in \Bbb R^n \quad (2)$$

I want to make sure I follow this answer:

Suppose $\vec y$ is arbitrary vector in $\Bbb R^n$ and let $\vec x = S(y)$. Then $$T(\vec x) = T(S(\vec y)) = \vec y \quad (3)$$

Which shows $T$ maps $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R^n$.

This is what I get from this: $\vec x$ lives in the domain of $T$. $\space \vec y$ lives in the codomain of $T$, and the inverse of $T$, i.e., $S$,  transforms it into $\vec x$. Because of (2), no matter what $\vec x$ I choose, I will always get an arbitrary $\vec y \in \Bbb R^n$ which means $T$ maps onto $\Bbb R^n$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, this line of thought is fine. can you explain why it is also one-one? (if it is invertible). Furthermore, can you show why, if $T$ is one-one and onto, then it is invertible?

Comment: Your official proof was fine, but your (next to) final sentence is not so good. Part of the confusion, perhaps, comes from using $\vec x$ in both sentences (1) and (2). If you want $\vec x$ in the domain and $\vec y$ in the codomain (which I'm fine with), use $\vec y$ in sentence (2).

Comment: @TedShifrin Yea sorry about that. (1) and (2) are just definitions of what it means for $T$ to be invertible.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Thanks. Yeah, for one-to-one I just have to show that $T(u) = T(v)$ for some u,v in R^n.

Comment: For one-one, you have to show that no two elements of $\mathbb R^n$ have the same image under $T$, that is, if $u \neq v$ then $T(u) \neq T(v)$. Assuming $T$ is invertible, can you try to show this?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Take two vectors $u$ and $v$. Then, set $T(u) = T(v) \implies S(T(u)) = S(T(v)) \implies u = v$. Thus, $u, v$ are the same and thus one-to-one. Correct?

Comment: @Romaion Correct, well done. Now, suppose I give you that $T$ is one-one and onto, then can you prove it is  invertible?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I'm not sure how to prove the general case - although if I had the standard matrix I could do it.

Comment: It has nothing to do with matrix theory really : all you need is a  well defined inverse. This is easy : since $T$ is surjective and injective, if we define $S(x) = y$ where $y$ is the unique (by injectivity) element such that $T(y)=x$ (the fact that there is at least one such $y$ comes from surjectivity), then you can see that $S$ is the inverse of $T$.